# Converting between Windows CryptoAPI and OpenSSL x509 formats

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptoapi, x509, asn.1

I have a [CERT_CONTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377189%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure which I've extracted from a smart card on Windows via the CryptoAPI. I need to convert this structure into a DER encoded byte array which is consistent with OpenSSL. The closest match I've got so far is via [CryptEncodeObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using X509_ASN_ENCODING and the X509_CERT_TO_BE_SIGNED modifier which takes the [CERT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure as input.

The problem is that it doesn't match with the output produced by the OpenSSL [i2d_X509](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/d2i_X509.html) function. Using a 2048 bit x509 certificate as input, OpenSSL produces 1789 bytes of encoded output whilst the Windows CryptoAPI produces 1638 bytes of encoded output.

The only option left that I can see is to create an X509 cert on the fly using the values from the [CERT_CONTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377189%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure and the encode the resulting object directly with the [i2d_X509](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/d2i_X509.html) function. The only problem with this is that I can't extract the private key from the smart card, so this may cause problems with the x509 cert creation routines.

If anyone can provide any insight/advice/tips into these matters, I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DER encoded certificate can be obtained from (ctx->pbCertEncoded, ctx->cbCertEncoded) buffer where ctx is a PCCERT_CONTEXT object. Still you won't be able to recover the private key.

Comment: Argh!, right in front of me the whole time :), Thanks, I would never have found this otherwise, I had my mind set on using the CryptEncodeObject function. I don't need the private key, I'm using the public key encoding as the source data for a signing operation.